# How do I interpolate light intensity for tilemap's lightmap?

Tags: opengl, glsl, tilemap, lightmap

I implemented lightmap creation for a tilemap, but I cannot figure out how do I interpolate light intensity values. For now, my lighted tiles create an obvious grid-like structure. It was pretty easy to interpolate via GLSL fragment shader because I could control every fragment of a mesh and therefore calculate the intensity using distance between fragment and light source. Downside is that [shader solution](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/208885/how-to-setup-gradient-lighting-in-opengl-shader) was limited because of inability to process changing quantity of light sources.

Since a tile layer has one mesh for all tiles, I am not able to control fragment set of exact tile. I create the lightmap using positions of each tile, I then calculate the intensity using the distance between the tile and the light source. Therefore the whole tile is lighted with a single light intensity value.

I also create a single mesh for a whole lightmap. I need some kind of control over color of tiles' fragments, but I cannot create a separate mesh for each tile. Maybe is there any technique to mix/interpolate colors of adjacent fragments?

Current fragment shader code for lightmap:

```
in vec4 vColor;
out vec4 fColor;

uniform float alpha;

void main(void)
{
    fColor = vColor;
    fColor.a = alpha;
}
```

How do I interpolate light intensity of my light map?

[image]
[image]

**EDIT:**

I managed to render Lightmap to a texture using the Framebuffer.
(I basically used another render target while drawing the Lightmap as a set of colored tiles)
I then set the texture's parameters like this:

```
setParameter(GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR) 
setParameter(GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
```

Shader is pretty simple:

```
in vec2 fragmentUV;
out vec4 fColor;
uniform sampler2D textureSample;

void main(void)
{
    fColor = texture(textureSample, fragmentUV).rgba;

    if (fColor.a <= 0){
        discard;
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally the term "lightmap" is used to describe a texture. Storing your lighting in a texture would let you get bilinear interpolation basically for free, and you could write custom sampling code if you want a different filter.